# How to prove NOT big omega?

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, asymptotics

I understand how to prove a function f(n) is $\Omega(g(n))$ - just find a positive $c$ and $a$ such that $ cg(x)) \leq f(x) $ for all $ x \gt a$ - but I'm not sure how to begin a proof that says $f(n)  \not \subseteq \Omega (g(n))$.

The specific problem I'm working on is: $ f(n)=2^{n}, g(n)=2^{n+1}$ (trivial, I know)

Comment: You have to invert some quantifiers: you need to show that for every $c>0,a>0$ there exists $x>a$ such that $cg(x)>f(x)$. But to save you some time, let me tell you that this will not be possible for those $f,g$. So you may want to check your reference's definition of $f=\Omega(g)$, because it might be the same as $g=o(f)$ (which would not be the definition that you gave here).